# Using onEdit installable trigger, how do I call a function when a specific value is selected in any of a range of cells(all with dropdowns)?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a range of cells in a sheet with a list of dropdown values.
I have setup an installable trigger to use onEdit.
I written simple functions to call different google forms in a sidebar depending on the which value is selected in the dropdown.

Range of cells : J4:P20
Each cell has a dropdown with three options   A, B and C
If I choose A, I want to call function A which will load sidebar A
If I choose B, I want to call function B which will load sidebar B etc

The sidebars are created.

I just need a complete example of an onEdit function that will call sidebar A,B or C depending on which value is selected in each of the dropdowns in each cell of the specified range.

This is my poor pseudo attempt.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActive()
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet()
  var values = sheet.getRange("J4:P20").getValues();
  Logger.log(values);
  var cellContent = values.getValue()
  if cellcontent = SQL {
   loadsqlSideBar();
  }
  else if cellcontent = ORACLE {
   loadoracleSideBar();
  }
  else if cellcontent = IMANIS {
   loadimanisSideBar();
  }
}



function loadsqlSideBar()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sql');//sidebar for html and formBar for form
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}

function loadoracleSideBar()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('oracle');//sidebar for html and formBar for form
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}


function loadimanisSideBar()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('imanis');//sidebar for html and formBar for form
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onEdit(e) {
  if(e.value=='SQL') loadsqlSideBar();
  if(e.value=='ORACLE') loadoracleSideBar();
  if(e.value=='IMANIS') loadimanisSideBar();
}
```

Comment: Hi. Where are you defining the range of cells?  Should this only require one installable trigger?  There are three functions, one for each sidebar.  How do I set up a trigger that will call them?  Sorry but I am working this out with examples and trial and error.  I'm not a coder.  If you could provide a bit more info, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

In order for you to solve your issue, you will need to use **event objects** in order to monitor the edited cell.

#### Snippet

```
function onEditTrigger(e) {
  var cellEdited = e.range.getValue();
  if (cellEdited == "SQL") {
   loadsqlSideBar();
  }
  else if (cellEdited == "ORACLE") {
   loadoracleSideBar();
  }
  else if (cellEdited == "IMANIS") {
   loadimanisSideBar();
  }
}


function loadsqlSideBar()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('sql');//sidebar for html and formBar for form
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}

function loadoracleSideBar()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('oracle');//sidebar for html and formBar for form
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}


function loadimanisSideBar()
{
  var userInterface=HtmlService.createHtmlOutputFromFile('imanis');//sidebar for html and formBar for form
  SpreadsheetApp.getUi().showSidebar(userInterface);
}
```

#### Explanation

The `onEditTrigger` function is an installable trigger which means that it will trigger once an `edit` action is detected. The main difference between an installable and a simple trigger is that they can call services which require authorization and they offer more flexibility. There is no need to specify the range `J4:P20` since you will gather the edited cell and you will check if its value is one of the wanted ones.

Therefore, the above script makes use of the `e` event object in order to detect which cell has been edited and then based on its value, it loads the sidebar.

#### Installing the Trigger

In order to have an installable trigger, you will need to install it. To do so, you will need to go to your project's triggers by clicking this icon.

[image: triggers icon]

Afterwards, you will need to create a new trigger with the following options:

[image: trigger settings]

#### Note

Also don't forget to use the correct way for an `if` structure.

#### Reference

- [Event Objects Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events);
- [Installable Triggers Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/installable);
- [if...else Structure JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/if...else).